# Place multiple markers on google map with callback function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to implement a functionality on Gmap API, that if the zoom is more than 17, show all the markers(otherwise, just hide them). However, when I write code like the following, it just does not work.

PS: the code might not be exactly correct in syntax and arrangement, but it express what I mean

```
// @latlong is an array of tuple (latitude , longtitude)
// @myMap is the google map object passed to the function
function placeMarker( myMap , latlon)
{
  for(var i = 0 ; i < latlon.length ; i ++)
  {
     myMarker = new google.maps.Marker( {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(latlon[i][0], latlon[i][1])
     });

     google.maps.event.addListener(myMap, 'zoom_changed', function() {
      zoomLevel = myMap.getZoom()       
      if(zoomLevel >= 17)
      {
        myMarker.setMap(myMap)
      }
      else
      {
        myMarker.setMap(null)
      }
  });


}
}
```

And I just change my code to:

```
function placeMarker( myMap , latlon)
{
  for(var i = 0 ; i < latlon.length ; i ++)
  {
     myMarker = new google.maps.Marker( {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(latlon[i][0], latlon[i][1])
     });

     (function(myMarker_copy){
         google.maps.event.addListener(myMap, 'zoom_changed', function() {
          zoomLevel = myMap.getZoom()       
          if(zoomLevel >= 17)
          {
            myMarker_copy.setMap(myMap)
          }
          else
          {
            myMarker_copy.setMap(null)
          }
      });
      }(myMarker));


}
}
```

And the second version works.
I know how to make it work, however, I really do not know why it work and why the other does not. Maybe this has something to do with the function closure or parameter passing principle of JS(I have checked a lot references, but some of them just hold different ideas). Could anybody give me a help?

really appreciate it.

Comment: If the latlon variable is an array of tuples, then latlon[0] is a tuple as well as latlon[1]. You need to pass the marker constructor the tuple values, not the tuple itself. position: ```position :new google.maps.LatLng(latlon[i][0], latlon[i][1]) ```

Comment: Yes, that is a typo, and I have revised that

Answer (score 0):

The first example which doesn't work: There is one global variable `myMarker` and many event listeners which at the end all operate on one marker and that is the one created the last in the loop.

The second example which does work: because of closure each event listener receive its own local copy of marker variable. So, when event listener is called it has correct marker value.

Comment: Yes, but I think the JS would pass the myMarkder variable by reference but not by deep copy...so if you say this is because the closure of the function, then the parameter myMarker_copy should still point to the same object

Comment: I think that explanation lies in the fact that function arguments are passed by value. Even though for objects it seems that they are passed by reference. But still they are passed by value.

Comment: Inner function (in this case event handler) gets access to the parameters and variables of the function it is defined within (the function has access to the context in which it was created). Event handler function is bound to the object which was passed in, not to the object defined outside of enclosing function.

Comment: OK~Still a little confused with the js function parameter passing...but anyway u helped a lot thx